# Convergence of integrals in an arbitary Rieszspace

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Hello i have a question about integration theory:

The situation: Let $X$ be a set, $F$ a Rieszspace of $X$ and $\varphi$ an integral on $F$. Now we can extend this to the space of all integrable functions say the space $\mathcal{L}$ with the new integral $\int$ which extends $\varphi$. Let $\mathcal{L}^+$ be space of all positive integrable function. Let $f\in\mathcal{L}^+$ and $(f_n)_n$ a sequence in $\mathcal{L}^+$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. I want to prove the following:
$$\int f=\lim{\int(\min(f,f_n))}$$
I think that we have to use the Theorem of Levi of the Theorem of Lebesgue, but can someone mayke this explicit by giving me some hints for this?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you can yous Lebesgues Theorem since $g_n=min(f,f_n)\rightarrow f$ a.e. and $|g_n|\leq f$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is this a good argumentation?